# Html br tag control

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Am having a page and i want the `<br>` tag inside div class `.this` to work when the page is browsed on mobile device

and not to work when browsed on pc - computer

```
<html>
  <header>
    <title>This is title</title></header>
  <body>
    Hello world
    <div class="this">
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <span>ok</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mediaquerie and height, padding, margin can help to avoid the div and its  br. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: some example and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved via css media queries:

```
.this br {
    display: none;
}
    
@media (max-width : 600px) {
    .this br {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

The resolution can be argued here (600px). If you want to make [absolutely](http://mobiledetect.net/) certain that it only affects mobiles, you should use a php library like MobileDetect to determine if the user is on mobile, and load an additional css file displaying the `<br>` tags then.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution (to be expanded as desired): Use a media query that hides the `br` tag above a certain width:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .this br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
Hello world
<div class="this">
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<span>ok</span>
```

Comment: This will work, just change max-width to min-width. Otherwise it does the opposite now.

Comment: @Andrew You are right, I changed it accordingly... - thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with the `@media screen`,
Show it in mobile size and hide it in larger sizes

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">
  .this br{display: none;}

  @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px){ 
      .this br{display: block;}
  }
</style>
<body>
Hello world
<div class="this">
<br>
</div>
<span>ok</span>
</body>
</html>
```